# liquibase-maven-plugin error jakarta/validation/ValidatorFactory when I use liquibase:diff

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, liquibase

I'm integrating liquibase-maven-plugin into my spring boot project.

I can use the plugin for `mvn liquibase:update` and `mvn liquibase:dropAll` work correctly.

But when I try to use the `mvn liquibase:diff` to generate the new changelog files, I get this error that I'm unable to resolve.

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:4.23.2:diff (default-cli) on project work-with-liquibase: Execution default-cli of goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:4.23.2:diff failed: A required class was missing while executing org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:4.23.2:diff: jakarta/validation/ValidatorFactory`

Can you help me understand what dependencies the plugin needs? Are there perhaps errors of incompatible versions? The documentation is not very clear about this.
Thanks in advance to anyone who will try to help me.

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
</parent>


<properties>
        <spring.boot.version>${project.parent.version}</spring.boot.version>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <liquibase.maven>4.23.2</liquibase.maven>
</properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.6.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase.maven}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liquibase.maven}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/liquibase-local.properties</propertyFile>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>42.6.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${liquibase.maven}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate6</artifactId>
                        <version>${liquibase.maven}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

**liquibase-local.properties**

```
driver: org.postgresql.Driver
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my-db
username=username
password=password

changeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
outputChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
diffChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase/changelog/db.changelog_new.sql

databaseChangeLogTableName=myproject_databasechangelog
databaseChangeLogLockTableName=myproject_databasechangeloglock

referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:com.myproject.entities?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy

#referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:com.myproject.entities?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
```

**db.changelog-master.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-latest.xsd">

    <include file="liquibase/changelog/db.changelog_v1.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
    <include file="liquibase/changelog/db.changelog_v2.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: 'Can you help me understand what dependencies the plugin needs?' It's super easy to do it yourself. Have a look at the 'dependencies' section of the mvnrepository.com website entry for the plugin. However, seeing the error message, it is quite likely that the appropriate version of Hibernate Validator is what it needs

Comment: Are there any reasons why you define the version of hibernate-validator yourself? because it's already defined via the parent (yes the version for sb 3.1.1 ) is not the one you have defined that's exactly why I'm asking? It might better to go with the versions of SB itself instead manually defining versions.. Also I would recommend to use the latest version of liquibase ...

Comment: BTW: Spring Boot 3.2.0-M2 is using hibernate-validator version 8.0.1.Final .. so maybe it would be better to upgrade to SB 3.2.0-M2...

Answer (score 1):

I faced literally same scenario, except I didn't use `mvn liquibase:update` nor `mvn liquibase:dropAll`.

For me it finds out that `liquibase-maven-plugin` has its own dependencies and `ValidationFactory` from `jakarta.persistence-api` was missing. I fixed the issue by adding dependency to `jakarta.persistence-api` explicitly to Liquibase plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakarta.validation.api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```